# Incorporating UNION ALL with my intraday table

Tags: google-bigquery

I've seen several examples but I don't know how to format my query into a union that will incorporate my intraday table. The TABLE_SUFFIX is grabbing all my daily tables just fine but I need to also grab the intraday `smarttruck-6d137.com_usiinc_android_ANDROID.app_events_intraday_*`. Can someone help me with the UNION ALL formatting for this? Thank you.

```
SELECT
  event_dim.date AS Date,
  (
  SELECT
    value.value.string_value
  FROM
    UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties)
  WHERE
    key = 'imei_id') AS IMEI,
  (
  SELECT
    value.value.string_value
  FROM
    UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties)
  WHERE
    key = 'division_id') AS Branch,
  (
  SELECT
    value.value.string_value
  FROM
    UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties)
  WHERE
    key = 'truck_id') AS Truck,
  (
  SELECT
    value.value.string_value
  FROM
    UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties)
  WHERE
    key = 'installer_id') AS Installer,
  COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM
  `smarttruck-6d137.com_usiinc_android_ANDROID.app_events_*`
CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST(event_dim) AS event_dim
WHERE
  event_dim.name = 'app_exception'
  AND EXISTS (
  SELECT
    1
  FROM
    UNNEST(event_dim.params)
  WHERE
    key = 'fatal'
    AND value.int_value = 1 )
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX = Date
GROUP BY
  Date,
  IMEI,
  Branch,
  Truck,
  Installer
ORDER BY
  Date DESC,
  Count DESC;
```

Comment: Do you need to differentiate between the two tables in the result? Or is it sufficient to treat them as one common table?

Comment: A common table is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this works for you:

```
SELECT
  event_dim.date AS Date,
  (
  SELECT
    value.value.string_value
  FROM
    UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties)
  WHERE
    key = 'imei_id') AS IMEI,
  (
  SELECT
    value.value.string_value
  FROM
    UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties)
  WHERE
    key = 'division_id') AS Branch,
  (
  SELECT
    value.value.string_value
  FROM
    UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties)
  WHERE
    key = 'truck_id') AS Truck,
  (
  SELECT
    value.value.string_value
  FROM
    UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties)
  WHERE
    key = 'installer_id') AS Installer,
  COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM
  `smarttruck-6d137.com_usiinc_android_ANDROID.app_events_*`
CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST(event_dim) AS event_dim
WHERE
  event_dim.name = 'app_exception'
  AND EXISTS (
  SELECT
    1
  FROM
    UNNEST(event_dim.params)
  WHERE
    key = 'fatal'
    AND value.int_value = 1 )
  AND REGEXP_EXTRACT(_TABLE_SUFFIX, r'(\d+)') BETWEEN '20170807' and '20170809'
GROUP BY
  Date,
  IMEI,
  Branch,
  Truck,
  Installer
ORDER BY
  Date DESC,
  Count DESC;
```

You can change the days I used in the selection for what works best for you.

If you will be using the query in Data Studio, what I tend to do is to create a date range based on today's date and how many days to go back in time. Example:

```
AND REGEXP_EXTRACT(_TABLE_SUFFIX, r'(\d+)') BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) and FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))
```

This automatically will query over the last 30 days counting from today. You can adapt this query for what works best in your data studio report.

Comment: Another option (instead of a regex) would be to use `SUBSTR(_TABLE_SUFFIX, LENGTH(_TABLE_SUFFIX) - 7)`, but either should work fine.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Cool technique! will give it a try as well

Comment: @WillianFuks Beautiful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out myself. By removing the _TABLE_SUFFIX = Date in the where clause, BQ used the wildcard to grab my intraday table as well. I won't pretend I fully understand why this works but it does. Please chime in if you can explain.

standardSQL

```
SELECT
  event_dim.date AS Date,
  (
  SELECT
    value.value.string_value
  FROM
    UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties)
  WHERE
    key = 'imei_id') AS IMEI,
  (
  SELECT
    value.value.string_value
  FROM
    UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties)
  WHERE
    key = 'division_id') AS Branch,
  (
  SELECT
    value.value.string_value
  FROM
    UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties)
  WHERE
    key = 'truck_id') AS Truck,
  (
  SELECT
    value.value.string_value
  FROM
    UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties)
  WHERE
    key = 'installer_id') AS Installer,
  COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM
  `smarttruck-6d137.com_usiinc_android_ANDROID.app_events_*`
CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST(event_dim) AS event_dim
WHERE
  event_dim.name = 'app_exception'
  AND EXISTS (
  SELECT
    1
  FROM
    UNNEST(event_dim.params)
  WHERE
    key = 'fatal'
    AND value.int_value = 1 )
GROUP BY
  Date,
  IMEI,
  Branch,
  Truck,
  Installer
ORDER BY
  Date DESC,
  Count DESC;
```

Comment: Just make sure that you are not selecting over your whole dataset by removing the range filtering condition. Check how much data will be processed when you run this query.

Comment: What's happening here is that the `*` matches both kinds of suffixes, e.g. `20170807` and also `intraday_20170807`. Will's answer works by using a regex to extract the date part of the suffix.

Comment: Thank you both, I get where you're going. However, doesn't that just hardcode in my date range? I'll be using this in Data Studio so I'm going to want my dates to change based on user input.